# retain only unique values in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of strings. I need to retain only the unique values, ie. I want to remove all repititions. eg: if the array is {string1, string1, string1, string2, string3, string3} then the final array should be {string1, string2, string3}

```
for(int p = 0; p < [allNewsDates count]; p++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",allNewsDates[p]);
        for(int q = p+1; q < [allNewsDates count]; q++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@   %@",allNewsDates[p],allNewsDates[q]);
            if([allNewsDates[p] isEqualToString:allNewsDates[q]])
            {
                flag = YES;
                t = q;

                break;

            }
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            //[self.date addObject:allDates[p]];


            [allNewsDates removeObjectAtIndex:p];
            NSLog(@"%i",[allNewsDates count]);
        }

        NSLog(@"%i",p);
        flag = NO;
    }
```

I'm following the above procedure to extract unique dates from an array of all dates.
This normally works ok. But the problem is this:  I have a News view controller which shows news feed. If the user selects any news there, it gets added to favorites. If I select all the news items in one go, then the favorites table shows the news according to the date(different dates appear once say 9th and 10th of May), but if I add the news, go to favorites, then go back to news and click on some news item(say for 10th of May) and access favorites again, then I'm getting 10th May twice. Where am I going wrong? Please help!!

Comment: Add the values to an NSSet and then copy them back out. Sets don't allow duplicates.

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use KVC collection operators:

```
NSArray* uniqueDates = [allNewDates valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"]
```

More details here: http://www.nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators

Answer (score 6):

add your array to **NSSet**, thats it

```
NSSet *mySet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:allNewsDates];
NSArray *filteredArray = [mySet allObjects];
```

Comment: Why mutable? and you have my up vote if you show how to copy the values back to an array as well.

Comment: I just put the mutable part, coz if he is going to add more strings to the set, that'll be useful. :) Anyway Thankz

Comment: Totally work thank you better than `distinctUnionOfObjects.self`

Answer (score 3):

```
NSSet *uniqueStates = [NSSet setWithArray:yourArray];
NSArray *arr = [uniqueStates allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of removing duplicates values from NSMutable Array..it will work for you. myArray is your Mutable Array that you want to remove duplicates values..

```
for(int j = 0; j < [myArray count]; j++){
    for(int k = j+1;k < [myArray count];k++){
        NSString *str1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:j];
        NSString *str2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:k];
        if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
            [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:k];
       }
}
```

Or you can use :

An NSSet does exactly what you're trying to do: it is a (unordered) collection of unique items. So, you can find the unique items in your array like so:

```
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];
// iterate over the unique items
for(id element in uniqueElements) {
  // do something
}
```